# Running ArcGIS Desktop log file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, log

I read that arcgis saves all the processes in a log file, and I was wondering if I can run this log file and all of its processes in a free GIS software like QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot run ArcGIS tools in QGIS. The log file you're referring to is a .txt file that says tool x was run on (date/time) and was completed on (date/time).

Comment: Is it possible to change the file that was used in the log file an rerun those processes

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of this. One thing you could do is check what was run and then replicate the same or similar tools in QGIS.